# AWS fetching multiple images

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have following question:

In my first scenario i have an S3 bucket. I can use the `Storage` API from the amplify SDK

```
const result = await Storage.put("profile.png", profileImage, { level: "protected" });
```

and later i can get it

```
const result = await Storage.get("profile.png", { level: "protected" });
```

Everything works fine. Everybody can read it, but only i can read/delete/update it.

But now here my question....

In my application a user can be the admin of a group. He can see all group members.
What if he fetch the list of all users. Lets say he fetch 10 users. Does this mean i need to make 10 requests for each image? This also means i need to save somewhere the ID of the other user.

Is this the correct way?

Comment: I think you mean "10 requests, one for each image" rather than "10 requests for each image" (which would be 10x10).

Comment: @jarmod yes. i wrote it a bit wrong

Comment: If you want to expose pre-signed URLs for 10 images then you need to generate 10 unique URLS, one per call. The `Storage.get()` call is lightweight afaik, and simply generates a pre-signed URL locally.

Comment: @jarmod and what about storing the image URl into a datatable? So if i query the table i get automaticall the URL too so i get every URL and user information with 1 query?

Comment: I'm sure that's possible but bear in mind these pre-signed URLs are temporary and they will expire. You indicate what the expiration should be when you generate them. There's no cost to re-generating these URLs on demand.

Comment: @jarmod so, saving the url into the DB is not a good idea? When i want to display some other users profile i need his identity ID. Where do i get it? Can i store it into a dynamoDB table?

Comment: I don't see any value in persisting pre-signed URLs. I'd recommend that you get familiar with the API docs e.g. [admin queries](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/#enable-admin-queries) and try things out. You can retrieve a list of users in a specific group using `listUsersInGroup`, for example. You can list all users in the Cognito user pool using `listUsers` which will give you user identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js/#get) `Storage.get` returns a pre-signed URL. A pre-signed URL is for a *single* object so yes, for 10 users you'd need to make 10 `get` requests.

However, there may be alternatives depending on your app requirements. For example, a common approach for S3 is to use a key prefix to group items. You could prepend the group-name/group-id for all profile pictures of people within that group.

S3 allows listing keys by a prefix, which is the [`Storage.list`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/list/q/platform/js/) call. E.g. you could use a format like `s3://my-bucket/{group-id}/{user-id}/profile.png` then for the admin user you can get all items in the group with a call like `const result = await Storage.list('{group-id}/');`

Comment: i was thinking about to save the URL into a database field. Is this a better idea?

Comment: If you store the pre-signed URL then you'd need to be aware of how long it's valid for. You could store the path of the object in S3 instead and use that to generate a pre-signed URL.

Comment: alright. Does a method exists like "getPath"? Do you know some guide ressources where i can read that?

Comment: The path is just the key that you uploaded the item to, like `{group-id}/{user-id}/profile.png`.

Comment: there is this `identityId` option. How do i get this identity ID? My idea was to store this ID into an table. If i fetch the user datas, i fetch its profile image by its identityId